# Show Each Section Per button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

everyone.

I would like to ask if it is possible to show each section per button click in JQuery or JS?

```
<section style="display: none;">section1<section> 
<section style="display: none;">section2<section> 
<section style="display: none;">section3<section> 
<section style="display: none;">section4<section> 
<section style="display: none;">section5<section> 
<section style="display: none;">section6<section> 

<button>Show each per click</button>
```

Comment: Yes of course it's possible, but what have you tried and what is not working for you? If you google something like `jquery show element on button click` you get lots of answers.

Comment: Yes. I tried it but only 1 section. I don't know how can I do it multiple times.

Comment: Please include you attempt. Then it's easier for us to point out the problem.

Comment: Do you want to show all sections at once? Or iterate through and only show one section at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `index()` function .. See the next example

```js
$("button").on("click" , () => {
  let index = !$("section.show").length ||  $("section.show").index() == $("section").length ? 0 : $("section.show").index();
  $("section")                         // all sections
    .removeClass("show")               // remove show class to hide all sections
    .filter("section:eq("+index+")")   // desired section by index
    .addClass("show");                 // show the section
});

// to show spacific section
// index starts from 0 so 0 mean the first section change 0 to 1 or 2 ... and try it
$("section").eq(0).addClass("show");
```

```css
section{
  display : none;
}
section.show{
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>section1</section> 
<section>section2</section> 
<section>section3</section> 
<section>section4</section> 
<section>section5</section> 
<section>section6</section> 

<button>Show each per click</button>
```